# Delete row clistview doesn't work anymore

Tags: yii

I have a delete function in a CListView, which used to work, but doesn't anymore.

In the CListView I have:

```
echo CHtml::link('<img src="images/delete.png" />',
                    $this->createUrl('persoon/delete',array('id'=>$data->id)),
                    array(// for htmlOptions
                      'onclick'=>' {'.CHtml::ajax( array(
                           'beforeSend'=>'js:function(){if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"))return true;else return false;}',
                           'success'=>"js:function(html){ alert('removed'); }"
                           )).
                         'return false;}',// returning false prevents the default navigation to another url on a new page 
                    'class'=>'delete-icon')
                );
```

The controller is unedited:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
    }
```

There is no error, but it just doesn't remove an item when clicked. Does someone know what happened here?

Comment: What does the http request return?

Comment: Think it returns nothing now. Don't really understand why it used to work, because when i change the url to 

$this->createUrl('test/test',array('id'=>$data->id)),

then it doesn't give any errors while this page doesn't excist. Is there something the page persoon/delete should do?

Comment: and the beforeSend event is executed?

Comment: yes, and the succes too

Comment: I thought the controller handles it right away... Is this correct?